# Why does mappings in Universal have no effect on what's included in tarball?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

A summary of my `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
import com.github.bigtoast.sbtliquibase.LiquibasePlugin
import S3._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.Universal
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import Path.flat

mappings in Universal ++= {
  ((baseDirectory.value / "src/main/migrations" * "*").get map { f => f -> (f.name) })
}
```

When I run `universal:packageZipTarball` I expect the files I have in `src/main/migrations` to appear in the final tarball. They don't.

What I see is:

```
a database2-0.34.0
a database2-0.34.0/lib
a database2-0.34.0/lib/com.trailhunger.database2-0.34.0.jar
a database2-0.34.0/lib/org.postgresql.postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc4.jar
a database2-0.34.0/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar
```

Very similar code in a another project in my build works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your build works fine for me.

Here's the complete `build.sbt` to reproduce your issue:

```
packageArchetype.java_application

mappings in Universal ++= {
  ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "migrations" * "*").get.map { f => 
    f -> (f.name)
  }
}
```

The point to remember is to place `packageArchetype.java_application` before setting the keys yourself in the build as the order does matter.

Other than the ordering, there is a small change with `sourceDirectory in Compile` that gives me the proper `src/main` directory without concatenating the paths myself.

```
> show sourceDirectory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/src
> show compile:sourceDirectory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/src/main
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.6-M1
```

**project/sbt-native-packager.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.4")
```

Under `src/main/migrations` I have one file - `migration1.txt` - that gets added to the final tarball.

```
> universal:packageZipTarball
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/target/scala-2.10/sbt-native-packager-playground_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
a sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT
a sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib
a sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT/migration1.txt
a sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/default.sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
a sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 9, 2014 10:17:37 PM
```

This is the value of `universal:mappings` for reference:

```
> show universal:mappings
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/target/scala-2.10/sbt-native-packager-playground_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] ArrayBuffer((/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/target/scala-2.10/sbt-native-packager-playground_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,lib/default.sbt-native-packager-playground-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar), (/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar,lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar), (/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-native-packager-playground/src/main/migrations/migration1.txt,migration1.txt))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 9, 2014 10:16:27 PM
```

Comment: Hi Jacek, I liked the (sourceDirectory in Compile). That was a nice touch. Sadly still not working for me. Would relying on having the two files in project/ in the root module be an issue? I don't see how the task would run if it were.